# Cassandra pagination traversing solutions

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to backwards traversing in cassandra with pagination. Basically we can traverse forward with the help of page states but how to traverse backwards. Like if i traverse to page no 5 then how can i back to page number 1 using prev button